# How to sanitize Textarea while keeping linebreaks?

Tags: php

I want to be able to clean my Textarea POST without getting rid of the linebreaks.

If I have a textarea with content:

```
a
b
c
```

and send that content using POST

If I set the value and sanitize it with `FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING`:

```
$obsCentrais = $_POST['obsCentrais'];
$obsCentrais = filter_var($obsCentrais, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

the output returns

```
abc
```

How can I clean the Textarea without losing the linebreaks?

Comment: replace line breaks with `<br/>` then trim

Comment: See [`nl2br()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php)

Comment: What do you want to clean it from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should user `nl2br()`

```
$obsCentrais = nl2br($_POST['obsCentrais']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
$string = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $obsCentrais);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
//this is a secure way to store and process strings on server
$filteredString=addcslashes($str);

//this is a get the original string back
$filteredString=stripcslashes ($str);
```